Best Approach for Buying New Tokens on Solana Chain from a Server Node
I'm researching the best approach for buying new tokens on the Solana blockchain and would appreciate your advice. I intend to execute this from a node on the server side.
I understand that Project Serum is no longer active. I've come across the Raydium SDK on GitHub and have also seen the token-swap program on Solana SPL.
Could you please advise on the best approach between these options or suggest any other methods you prefer? Specifically, I'm looking for the simplest solution with good liquidity or being more one or the other.
Thank you!

You can look at these repos to begin with:
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V2-demo
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-cp-swap/tree/master/programs/cp-swap
The pool creating SDK could also be interesting for advanced developers:
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-amm
Not sure about this one...
https://github.com/kevinheavey/raydium-ammv3-sdk
